# Safely add a new item instance into an std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

kind of a silly question but I have a metaphysical doubt which is why I need to ask.

When pushing back an object to a vector, assuming I do not need to update the object beforehand, can I avoid the usage of a local variable ?

```
void addToVector(std::vector<Foo>& fooVector)
{
    // Solution #1
    Foo foo;
    fooVector.push_back(foo);
    // Solution #2
    fooVector.push_back(Foo());
}
```

Would **solution #2** leak memory knowing that there is no local variable going out-of-scope encapsulating Foo ?

Assuming **solution #2** is valid, is it more efficient than **solution #1** ? (`emplace_back` would probably be, but I'm still stuck with c++03)

Comment: In general terms, they are equivalent.    The first constructs a named variable that is copied into the vector, and destroyed when it passes out of scope.   The second constructs am unnamed temporary that is copied into the vector, and destructed at the end of the statement.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`push_back` copies the item into the vector, so as you say `emplace_back` would be most efficient.

Your use of the temporary `Foo()` doesn't leak.